# Why does space with catcode 12 yield a weird dash?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

For fun, let’s change the category code of space to `12`. Then we get the following weird dash instead of a space. Why?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\catcode` =12

Hello World, how are you?

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get something different when you do `\usepackage[T1]{fonrtenc}`

Comment: @egreg Yes, you probably get an error message saying that package `fonrtenc` was not found. `;-)`

Comment: Oh, well, who doesn't make typos? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Of course everyone makes tyops. But with you saying that “you get something different”, this one was too good to ignore. `;-)` Good luck tonight! `:-D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the 7-bit OT1 encoding, trying to fit enough characters in to just 128 slots is challenging so they are all filled including control character positions and as TeX basically never sets a space using a space character that slot was also free. It is actually the slash used to construct the slashed l `\l` character,

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\l}{OT1}
   {\hmode@bgroup\@xxxii l\egroup}
```

`\@xxxii` is defined via \chardef 32 which is space.

Comment: Makes sense. Could you, in principle, redefine this behaviour (with either font encoding) so that space had category code `12` and still yielded a space character? Part of my reason for this curiosity is that, in a way, I dislike the TeX behaviour of gobbling spaces after command names.

Comment: @Gaussler not 12 as you can't get stretchy inter word space you could make it catcode13 but stuff wouldbreak.

Comment: What is done in `\ExplSyntaxOn`?

Comment: @Gaussler space is then given catcide ignore so it doesn't make a token at all

Comment: And is `~` still an active character, or is it receiving catcode space?

Comment: @Gaussler `~` has category code 10 in that case. And it will become a pair (32,10) because TeX normalizes all category code 10 characters to have character code 32 (well, funny spaces exist…).

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Now tonight, please defend the EU for all of us. `;-)` (sorry, David `;-)`)